# Converting pages files using Libreoffice in Docker returns empty file

Tags: c#, docker, libreoffice

I am trying to run LibreOffice in a Docker container to convert some pages files to PDF. The application is a Web API and runs perfectly on a Windows Virtual Machine. I am new to Linux, Dockers and Containers.

I have been able to deploy everything to a container and call the API, but I am just getting an empty document back, and I have no idea why. I'm also unsure on the best way to try and debug this issue, so any advice is greatly appreciated.

Here is how I am installing Libre Office in the Docker file.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
EXPOSE 80
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libreoffice
```

Here is the relevant part of my application responsible for doing the conversion.

```cs
string libreOfficeArgs = "--norestore --nofirststartwizard --headless --convert-to pdf \"{inputFile}\" --outdir \"{outputFolder}\"";
string libreOfficeExe = "/usr/bin/libreoffice";
//string libreOfficeExe = "/usr/bin/soffice"; Doesn't work either.

var conversionArgs = libreOfficeArgs.Replace("{inputFile}", inputPath).Replace("{outputFolder}", Path.GetDirectoryName(inputPath));

var conversionProcess = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = libreOfficeExe,
        Arguments = conversionArgs
    }
};

conversionProcess.Start();
await conversionProcess.WaitForExitAsync(); //TODO: Timeout?
conversionProcess.Close();

//I then read the output file into a stream and the API returns the stream
```

Any advice on how to investigate further or fix my problem would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I can see in the logs the following so I think it could be related to how I am installing LibreOffice? As clearly the API is calling it.

> convert /tmp/tmpuYq5ri.pages -> /tmp/tmpuYq5ri.pdf using filter : writer_Pdf_Export

EDIT 2:

Here is how the stream is being read.

```
var outputFilePath = Path.ChangeExtension(inputPath, "pdf");

var ms = new MemoryStream();
using (var fs = new FileStream(conversionOutput, FileMode.Open))
{
    await fs.CopyToAsync(ms);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
}
```

Comment: @MarcSances I have added this in EDIT 2. The API works absolutely fine on Windows and the logs show it is definitely trying to convert, so I'm convinced the problem is with the LibreOffice install somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to convert a `.pages` file. According to [this source](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/can-i-import-a-pages-document/52124) and [this bug](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=139175), trying to convert a pages file in old versions of LibreOffice yields a blank document, which would explain your issue.

Try updating LibreOffice to a version where this bug is fixed by modifying your `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
EXPOSE 80
RUN apt-get install libreoffice-java-common
ADD https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/tdf/libreoffice/stable/7.4.3/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_7.4.3_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz .
RUN tar zxvf LibreOffice_7.4.3_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz
RUN sh -c 'cd LibreOffice_7.4.3.2_Linux_x86-64_deb/DEBS && sh -c dpkg -i *.deb'
```

Also note the path of libreoffice is different. `/opt/libreoffice7.4/program/soffice`

Comment: Hmm interesting, the bug says resolved. But this is the issue. Using a word document returned the conversion correctly. However, the pages document converts correctly using a Windows Server 2019 VM so I guess this is a Linux issue. That's a shame, guess I have to stick with the Windows VM, thanks for your help!

Comment: or it's a version issue, what is the output of: `libreoffice --version` ?

Comment: @Luuk `7.0.4.2 00(Build:2)` which does seem a bit old. Libre Office is now on version 7.4. So I guess the question is now, how do I amend my docker file to install the latest version of Libre Office?

Comment: @MarcSances Thank you, I'll give this a go now and let you know how I get on. Thank you again :)

Comment: @MarcSances `dpkg -i LibreOffice_7.4.3_Linux_x86-64_deb.deb` currently fails with `No such file or directory`, investigating why it can't seem to find it.

Comment: Ahhhh, I've found the issue! I do need to cd into the DEBS folder and dpkg *.deb. But there was a little catch the download name is 7.4.3 but once its extracted the name is 7.4.3.2! I will shortly edit your answer with the additional steps and accept it.

Comment: @MarcSances Unfortunately I can't use *.deb in a Docker file, so need to try something else ahhh.

Comment: @MarcSances That worked, but now `libreoffice --version` just says it's not found. Urgh. Had no issues at all on Window Server, I hate Linux with a passion.

Comment: No luck there. However libreoffice7.4 --version tries to do something, however it errors. `error while loading shared libraries: libXinerama.so.1: cannot open shared object file`

Comment: using libreoffice7.4 --headless --version results in the same error. How would I go about installing a headless version? I would suspect the downloaded .deb files to contain all the dependencies for an application, because that's what an installer should do. High tempted to throw the Linux stuff in the bin :(

Comment: maybe try ``RUN apt-get -f install`` after installing the deb files, to fix any possible broken dependencies?

Comment: I'll try that instead! However I finally got it to run!!! and convert the apple documents!! Had to install some additional dependencies `apt-get install -y default-jre` and `apt-get install -y libreoffice-java-common` I spun up another docker and installed just the second package, and that one appears to be the key!